# tar slow on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, tar

I have two servers (accessed via SSH of the Internet), one with a high-end CPU and 32GB RAM. However, when I try to tar a large number of files (about 400,000) via the command:

```
tar cvf archive.tar folder
```

It take about 2 hours. When I execute the same command on my computer, which has a similar spec, but less RAM, it takes about 5 minutes to tar a similar batch of files.

Does anyone have any ideas or alternatives? The command line outputs a list of all the files. I don't know if this causes issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disk fragmentation.  If they are large files you can use `filefrag` to check how fragmented the individual files are, but there is another kind of fragmentation that tends to happen with many small files:  the order that the names appear in the directory may be completely different from the order that the inodes appear on disk, and that order may be completely different from the order of the data blocks on disk.  That means when you open all of the files in the order their names appear in the directory, the disk has to seek a lot and slows things down.  I wrote the following python script once to compute the correlation between names, inodes, and the first data block of all files in the current directory so you can measure this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from stat import *
import fcntl
import array

names = os.listdir('.')
lastino = 0
name_to_ino_in = 0
name_to_ino_out = 0
lastblock = 0
name_to_block_in = 0
name_to_block_out = 0
iblocks = list()
inode_to_block_in = 0
inode_to_block_out = 0

for file in names :
    try :
        st = os.stat(file)
    except OSError:
        continue
    if not S_ISREG(st.st_mode) :
        continue
    if st.st_ino > lastino :
        name_to_ino_in += 1
    else : name_to_ino_out += 1
    lastino = st.st_ino    
    f = open(file)
    buf = array.array('I', [0])
    err = fcntl.ioctl(f.fileno(), 1, buf)
    if err != 0 :
        print "ioctl failed on " + f
    block = buf[0]
    if block != 0 :
        if block > lastblock :
            name_to_block_in += 1
        else : name_to_block_out += 1
        lastblock = block
        iblocks.append((st.st_ino,block))
print "Name to inode correlation: " + str(float(name_to_ino_in) / float((name_to_ino_in + name_to_ino_out)))
print "Name to block correlation: " + str(float(name_to_block_in) / float((name_to_block_in + name_to_block_out)))
iblocks.sort()
lastblock = 0
for i in iblocks:
    if i[1] > lastblock:
        inode_to_block_in += 1
    else: inode_to_block_out += 1
    lastblock = i[1]
print "Inode to block correlation: " + str(float(inode_to_block_in) / float((inode_to_block_in + inode_to_block_out)))
```

Old filesystems that have had many small files added over a long time tend to get in bad shape.  Simply copying the entire directory may result in the destination being much better, then you can delete the original and replace it with the copy.  The second problem that contributes to this though is ext4's htree indexed directory feature, which is used on directories with many files in them to make looking up an individual file name much faster, but essentially completely randomizes the order of the names.  You can check if a directory is using htrees with `lsattr -d` and look for the `I` attribute.

One of the reasons that I prefer to backup with `dump` instead of `tar` is that it is immune to this problem since it reads all of the files in inode order regardless of the order the names appear in the directory.  It still has to contend with the inode to block fragmentation though.  A copy or a pass of `e2defrag` can help with that.

Comment: Thank you; this is very quick; for some usage instructions see: http://www.uptimemadeeasy.com/disaster-planning/dump-and-restore-for-linux-backup/

Comment: @KohjahBreese, you might see this answer for more information on how to use it for an automated, multi-level backup for servers: http://askubuntu.com/a/262359/8500